# Set a value to POD within 1 atomic operation in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, atomic

I am trying to find a way to set a POD (int, byte, long etc.) as atomic operation.
Notice std::atomic is not good for me because it is not POD.

I also looked in VC intrensic functions, but didn't find exactly what I wanted (guess due to lack of documentation).

Does anyone know how to do it?

EDIT: I did not know that std::atomic is POD, therefore my question was wrong, I'll reask it in a new question. I don't want to delete or alter this question because the answer is really good an informative. Thanks!!! My actual question: [Set a value to POD (that doesn't have constructor/desctructor) within 1 atomic operation in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719457/set-a-value-to-pod-that-doesnt-have-constructor-desctructor-within-1-atomic-o)

Comment: " to set a POD" ... "it is not POD"   ... this seems to contradict each other. Which is it, a POD or not? Maybe it would be clearest to just show code and what you want to have happen. It seems like `std::atomic` is what you're looking for.

Comment: `std::is_pod<std::atomic<int>>::value` is true according to GCC and clang (libstdc++ and libc++). A deleted copy constructor doesn't prevent it from being a POD type.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain better why std::atomic doesn't help in my case. I wasn't clear enough because I didn't know std::atomic is a POD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::atomic<T>`, contrary to what your question states it is a POD type. Let's go through the POD requirements one by one:

> **9 Classes [class]**
>
> 6 A *trivially copyable class* is a class that:
>
> - has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and

`std::atomic<T>` has no non-trivial copy or move constructors or assignment operators: it simply doesn't have them at all (they're deleted). It does have non-trivial non-copy non-move constructors and assignment operators, but that doesn't prevent the class from being trivially copyable.

> - has a trivial destructor (12.4).

`std::atomic<T>` has a trivial destructor, see 29.5.

> A *trivial class* is a class that has a trivial default constructor (12.1) and is trivially copyable.

`std::atomic<T>` has a trivial default constructor, see 29.5.

The requirements add up: `std::atomic<T>` is a trivial class.

> 10 A *POD struct* is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class,

`std::atomic<T>` is a non-union class, is a trivial class, and is a standard-layout class, see 29.5.

> and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).

If `std::atomic<T>` had any members of type non-POD struct or union, one of those members would have to be a non-trivial class or a non-standard-layout class. That would prevent `std::atomic<T>` from being a trivial class or a standard-layout class<sup>*</sup>, and since we have already determined that it *is* a trivial class and a standard-layout class, it cannot have such a member.

In the above, I've referred to 29.5. The relevant bit is p5:

> **29.5 Atomic types [atomics.types.generic]**
>
> 5 The atomic integral specializations and the specialization `atomic<bool>` shall have standard layout. They shall each have a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor. They shall each support aggregate initialization syntax.

<sub>* There is one exception: it is hypothetically possible for a trivial class to contain a non-trivial class member. For this to apply to `std::atomic<T>`, it pretty much requires malice on the part of the implementer, so outside of a hypothetical DeathStation 9000, I'm discounting that possibility.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for you detailed answer about std::atomic! I didn't know it is considered a POD! But it still doesn't answer my question. I have updated my question in order to explain better my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @TCS Unfortunately, having now looked into it, Microsoft's implementation of `std::atomic<T>` is non-conforming, because it doesn't have a trivial default constructor, even though the standard does require it to have one. "Use `std::atomic<T>`" *should be* the correct answer, I'm trying to think of a workaround that would let you use it.