# Set a value to POD (that doesn't have constructor/desctructor) within 1 atomic operation in VC++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, c++11

I am trying to find a way to set a POD that doesn't have constructor/destructor (int, byte, long etc.) as atomic operation.

The reason I need that is because I want to use __declspec(thread) in order to have a TLS "int" as a thread local storage. The thing is that current VC++ compiler doesn't support objects that have constructor/destructor, so I declared:

```
static __declspec(thread) int _thread_val;
```

Next, I want to set that `_thread_val` atomically.

Using std::atomic doesn't work because it has constructor/destructor, therefore it is not supported:

```
static __declspec(thread) std::atomic<int> _thread_val; //doesn't compile in VC++
```

I also looked in VC intrinsic functions, but didn't find exactly what I wanted (guess due to lack of documentation).

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I'm slightly confused, how could a TLS int be accessed by multiple threads at once and therefore require atomicity?

Comment: TLS implementation is system dependent, on some platform all TLS are mapped within the process address space, and the storage's base address is indexed, mostly with gs selector on x86 platform. On those system you may reference data from other thread's local storage directly with pointer, although in a very dirty manner, and totally beat the purpose of "thread local".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "set atomically"? Both x86 and x64 will do atomic writes to an aligned 32 bit int anyway. And you could use a compare and exchange to do more complex modifications.

Comment: Seeing as though you tagged `c++11` why aren't you using the `thread_local` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unfortunate that Microsoft's implementation of `std::atomic<T>` is non-conforming by not having a trivial default constructor. You may be able to work around that by using a wrapper class. Since you know that `std::atomic<T>` is supposed to be usable when it hasn't been constructed (since you know that it is supposed to be a POD type), and doesn't require destruction either, you can use `std::aligned_storage` to hold the object. Here's a starting point, it may need slight tweaking depending on the compiler-specific quirks you'll encounter.

```
template <typename T>
class atomic_wrapper
{
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(std::atomic<T>), alignof(std::atomic<T>)> data;
public:
    atomic_wrapper() = default;
    atomic_wrapper(const atomic_wrapper<T> &) = delete;
    std::atomic<T> &operator *() { return reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<T> &>(data); }
    std::atomic<T> *operator ->() { return &**this; }
};
```

Now, instead of declaring a variable as `std::atomic<int> a;`, declare it as `atomic_wrapper<int> a;`, and update your accesses to use `*a` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is within thread local storage, (and thus intended not access by other thread) what's the point for enforcing atomic operation?

Anyway, look at compiler intrinsics if you want to implement atomic integer yourself, start with _InterlockedAdd and its family.

For "Test & Set", VC++ provide _interlockedbittestandset function, which generate lock bts instruction on x86.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646k06sz(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646k06sz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

As a side note, there are also similar function for gcc.

Comment: The atomic operation is not for synchronization but for speed and evaluation (it is part of an academic research). And besides, it sounds weird that there is no way to set a value atomically. It should be some kind of "test-and-set".

Comment: "atomic" means "guaranteed not to be broken by a thread switch" (roughly) - it's nothing to do with speed

Comment: @MattMcNabb, when I write "atomic" I mean that it takes 1 operation of the CPU (like test-and-set), but thanks for making it clear, I didn't know that.

Comment: @TCS There IS test-and-set operation, defined by VC, gcc, and other as compiler extensions, intrinsics, or in newer C++ specifications. On system that do not natively provide those instruction, compiler generate emulation code that may even be slower.

Comment: @Calvin - I know, but the destination must be "volatile" and I am not sure how it effects the execution. That was my last resort if I had no choice.

Comment: @Calvin - In any way, please edit/write an answer with the test-and-set suggestion, seems like that's where I'm heading so if that is the case I'll make it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking.

```
void ChangeThreadVal(int nNew) {
  while (1) {
    int nOld = _thread_val;
    if (InterlockedCompareExchange(&_thread_val, nNew, nOld) == nOld)
      break; // success
    // if get here, had a race.  try again.
  }
}
```

Here is a more complex example of how to use InterlockedCompareExchange

```
class CItem {
  CItem*    m_pNext;
};

union CList {
  struct {
    QWORD   m_pHead   : 44,    // Address of first item in the list.
                      :  4,    // Spare
            m_nABA    : 16;    // Prevent the ABA scenario.  
                               // future expansion can use some of the ABA bits
  };
  QWORD     m_n64;             // atomically update struct by CAS on this

  CList() : m_n64(0)                      { }
  // This constructors are for making atomic copies.  
  // These cannot threadsafe update a shared instance.
  CList(volatile const CList& r) : m_n64(r.m_n64)        { }

  // push an item on the front of the list
  void Push(CItem *pItem) volatile {
    while (1) { // concurrency loop
      CList Old(*this), New(Old);
      New.m_pHead = UINT_PTR(pItem);
      New.m_nABA++;
      pItem->m_pNext = (CItem*)Old.m_pHead;
      if (CAS(&m_n64, Old.m_n64, New.m_n64))
        return; // success
      // if we get here means a race, loop back to try again
    }
  }

};

// here are our CAS macros
inline bool CAS(volatile WORD* p, const WORD nOld, const WORD nNew) { 
  Assert(IsAlign16(p)); 
  return WORD(_InterlockedCompareExchange16((short*)p, nNew, nOld)) == nOld; 
}

inline bool CAS(volatile DWORD* p, const DWORD nOld, const DWORD nNew) {
  Assert(IsAlign32(p)); 
  return DWORD(InterlockedCompareExchange((long*)p, nNew, nOld)) == nOld; 
}

inline bool CAS(volatile QWORD* p, const QWORD nOld, const QWORD nNew) {
  Assert(IsAlign64(p)); 
  return QWORD(InterlockedCompareExchange64((LONGLONG*)p, nNew, nOld)) == nOld; 
}

inline bool CAS(volatile PVOID* pp, const void *pOld, const void *pNew) {
  Assert(IsAlign64(pp)); 
  return PVOID(InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(pp, (LPVOID)pNew, (LPVOID)pOld)) == pOld; 
}

// requires 16 byte aligned
typedef struct { QWORD a[2]; }  U16, OWORD;
inline bool CAS(volatile OWORD* p, const OWORD* pOld, const OWORD* pNew) {
  OWORD OldTmp = *pOld;  
  return !!_InterlockedCompareExchange128((__int64*)p->a, pNew->a[1], pNew->a[0], (__int64*)OldTmp.a); 
}

inline bool IsAlign16(const volatile void *p) { return (UINT_PTR(p) & 1) == 0; } 
inline bool IsAlign32(const volatile void *p) { return (UINT_PTR(p) & 3) == 0; } 
inline bool IsAlign64(const volatile void *p) { return (UINT_PTR(p) & 7) == 0; }
```

Comment: The limitation of this method is that I must use volatile, which is okay, but I prefer without it.